# MediaPlayer main thread android

Tags: android

I was using `SoundPool`to play sound effects but now I need to switch to `MediaPlayer` as I need to listen to the `onCompletion` event to trigger a GUI change.

My questions are:

- The sound files are very small, less than 30kB, Can I use
  `MediaPlayer` in the main thread?
- Can I just call `mediaPlayer.stop()` after the play is done like so,

  ```
  mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
      //Do some GUI changes
      mediaPlayer.stop();
      mediaPlayer.release();
     }
  });
  ```

Then to play another effect will do this:

```
 mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
 mediaPlayer.start();
```

So, is it ok to create and release every time I play an effect?

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your `MediaPlayer`

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),    afd.getLength());
 afd.close();
```

Look at the `MediaPlayer` lifecycle:

[image]

When the track is complete the `MediaPlayer` is in `Stopped` state and you wan't to change the track, so:
call `reset()' to get to`Idle`then`setDataSource`then`prepare`and finally`start()`.

Answer (score 1):

> The sound files are very small, less than 30kB, Can I use MediaPlayer in the main thread?

Irrespective of the size of your audio file, you should run `MediaPlayer` on its own thread, especially if you are playing a file from network. Not doing so may cause ANR (In your case I don't think much to worry about)

> Can I just call mediaPlayer.stop() after the play is done

There is no need to release the `MediaPlayer` after every audio file. Release it once you are no longer going to use it.

> how can I load a new sound

```
AssetFileDescriptor audio = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.next_audio);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audio);
```